# Can randomization be proven?

Tags: randomness, permutations, lists

There exists a collection `c` where `c = {1, 2, 3}` and a randomization of `c`, `d` where `d = {1, 3, 2}`. `d` was obtained by a function `f` where `f` is an undefined randomization function.

Can `c` be obtained again (i.e. `d = c`) by randomizing

1. `d` or
2. `d` initially and then each randomized collection resulting from `d`

using `f`? If so, can it be proven?

Comment: By "randomization", do you mean "[permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)"? Otherwise, I'm not really sure what you're asking. (And, if you do mean permutation, can you explain why you feel that this is a computer science question, rather than pure mathematics?)

Comment: 1. Is `f` deterministic (will it give you the same answer every time, if you feed it the same input repeatedly)?  Or is it non-deterministic/randomized?  2. When you say "by randomizing", do you mean "by applying `f`"?  3. What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Did you try working through some small examples to see what seems to happen for them; look for a small counterexample; try to look for a pattern and form a conjecture and see if you can prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 0):

If *f* is a random permutation, then you can apply it to d and eventually get the ordering of C.

Comment: This is rather lacking in detail -- we're almost always looking for answers that are more than one sentence. For example, even repeatedly applying any fixed permutation enough times will return to the original ordering.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Make into an answer?